# Open another activity when dialog's button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'd like to successfully run the code below ([belonging to this library](https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker)) when any of the buttons from [this Rating Dialog](https://github.com/shurajcodx/android-app-rating-dialog) are pressed. How can I do it?

```
  public void goToPickerActivity() {
    Intent intent = new com.sucho.placepicker.PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
            .onlyCoordinates(true) //Get only Coordinates from Place Picker
            .showLatLong(true)
            .setLatLong(40.71274, -74.005974)  // Initial Latitude and Longitude the Map will load into (NYC coordinates)
            .setMapZoom(2.5f)  // Map Zoom Level. Default: 14.0
            .build(this);

    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
  }
```

Edit: I want to execute `goToPickerActivity()` **first** *and then* execute the library's intended click code. For example, when `Rate App` button is clicked:

Step 1 is: execute `goToPickerActivity()`.

Once that's complete, Step 2 is: run the usual `Rate App` clicked code.

Comment: what you mean "import library as a new module"? can you show your gradle configs?

Comment: I think you need to give us more details about your problem ... Is there any line pointed out by studio after clicking on that error ?

Comment: Did you add all the dependencies?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I added all dependencies.

Comment: Please add more code, what you tried so far. 'com.github.shurajcodx:android-app-rating-dialog:1.0.2' there are just 2 files in this library. Just copy the files in your code. Change the onClick method as want.

Comment: Otherwise use reflection to get the already set click listener, set your on clicklistener using findViewbyId and call the listener you got from reflection after your work is done.

Comment: I would really suggest you copy those files in your project and change code as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add a `OnRatingDialogListener` using `setRateButtonText`, `setRateLaterButtonText` or `setNeverRateButtonText` methods of `AppRatingDialog.Builder` class:

```
final AppRatingDialog appRatingDialog = new AppRatingDialog.Builder(this)
            // ... call another setup methods if need
            .setRateButtonText("Rate App", new OnRatingDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    goToPickerActivity();
                }
            })
            .setRateLaterButtonText("Rate App Later", new OnRatingDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    goToPickerActivity();
                }
            })
            .setNeverRateButtonText("Never", new OnRatingDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    goToPickerActivity();
                }
            })
            .build();

appRatingDialog.show();
```

Using lambda it will look like this:

```
final AppRatingDialog appRatingDialog = new AppRatingDialog.Builder(this)
        // ... call another setup methods if need
        .setRateButtonText("Rate App", () -> goToPickerActivity())
        .setRateLaterButtonText("Rate App Later", () -> goToPickerActivity())
        .setNeverRateButtonText("Never", () -> goToPickerActivity())
        .build();

appRatingDialog.show();
```

EDIT 1:

Method `openPlayStore`:

```
private void openPlayStore() {
    final String storeLink = "market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName();
    final Uri marketUri = Uri.parse(storeLink);
    try {
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Couldn't find PlayStore on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If you can edit the library try to make `openPlayStore` method `public`, save reference to `AppRatingDialog` instanse to some variable, e.g. `appRatingDialog` and call `appRatingDialog.openPlayStore()`.

EDIT 2:

To have different listeners for buttons we need to add new listeners to `AppRatingDialog` and handle them:

```
public class AppRatingDialog extends AppCompatDialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    //...
    private OnRatingDialogListener onRatingDialogListener;
    private OnRatingDialogListener onRateLaterDialogListener;
    private OnRatingDialogListener onRateNeverDialogListener;

    //...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_never_rate) {
            savedNeverShow();
            dismiss();

            if (onRateNeverDialogListener != null) {
                onRateNeverDialogListener.onClick();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate_later) {
            dismiss();
            incrementLaunchCount(true);

            if (onRateLaterDialogListener != null) {
                onRateLaterDialogListener.onClick();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate) {
            savedNeverShow();
            dismiss();

            if (onRatingDialogListener != null) {
                onRatingDialogListener.onClick();
            } else {
                openPlayStore();
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    public static class Builder {
        //...

        @NonNull
        public Builder setRateLaterButtonText(String rateLaterButtonText, @Nullable OnRatingDialogListener onRateLaterClickListener) {
            appRatingDialog.mRateLaterButtonText = rateLaterButtonText;
            appRatingDialog.onRateLaterDialogListener = onRateLaterClickListener;
            return this;
        }

        @NonNull
        public Builder setNeverRateButtonText(String neverRateButtonText, @Nullable OnRatingDialogListener onNeverRateClickListener) {
            appRatingDialog.mNeverRateButtonText = neverRateButtonText;
            appRatingDialog.onRateNeverDialogListener = onNeverRateClickListener;
            return this;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

To open Play Store and notify a listener simultaneously:

```
public class AppRatingDialog extends AppCompatDialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    //...
    private OnRatingDialogListener onRatingDialogListener;
    private OnRatingDialogListener onRateLaterDialogListener;
    private OnRatingDialogListener onRateNeverDialogListener;

    //...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_never_rate) {
            savedNeverShow();
            dismiss();

            if (onRateNeverDialogListener != null) {
                onRateNeverDialogListener.onClick();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate_later) {
            dismiss();
            incrementLaunchCount(true);

            if (onRateLaterDialogListener != null) {
                onRateLaterDialogListener.onClick();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate) {
            savedNeverShow();
            dismiss();

            openPlayStore();

            if (onRatingDialogListener != null) {
                onRatingDialogListener.onClick();
            }   
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But, I want to execute `goToPickerActivity()` **first** _and then_ execute the AppRatingDialog's intended click code.

Comment: For example, when `Rate App` button is clicked. Step 1 is: execute `goToPickerActivity()`. Once that's complete, step 2 is: run the usual `Rate App` clicked code.

Comment: If you want to open a play store, you can create method `openPlayStore` and call it whenever you want. Please see my edited answer. Using a library it's impossible since it has the `private` modifier.

Comment: Using the library is possible because I imported it as a module so I'm able to edit it

Comment: Please see my edited answer. But I think you don't need to modify a library code, you can just copy method `openPlayStore` from my answer  and call it when is necessary, it is less error prone.

Comment: There's a problem with your code. When `Rate App` is clicked, the code for the `Never` button is executed. The `RateApp` code doesn't get executed. Why?

Comment: You can try it out with print statements like this: 

`.setRateButtonText("Rate App", () -> System.out.println("rate now"))
.setRateLaterButtonText("Rate App Later", () -> System.out.println("later"))
.setNeverRateButtonText("Never", () -> System.out.println("never"))`

Comment: You need to change library's sources. As I can see there is only one reference to `OnRatingDialogListener` is used in the library. You need to add other two listeners and handle them.

Comment: please check EDIT 2 in my answer.

Comment: okay i tried it but now the play store doesn't open at all using the library only. why? you can try it out

Comment: When I add this `setRateButtonText("Rate app", new OnRatingDialogListener() { @Override public void onClick() {} })` the Play Store doesn't open anymore

Comment: Did it open before? I don't think so) The logic was the following: if you set a listener, you handle the click and Play Store is not open. Try it out with previous implementation. If you want to open Play Store and add listener simultaneously, check my EDIT 3.

Comment: Edit 3 already there. All logic of handling buttons' click events is placed in `AppRatingDialog.onClick(View v)`, you can manipulate it however you want)

Comment: Okay this is good. The only problem is that after returning from the Play Store to the app, the map from `goToPickerActivity` is not open like it should be. Can this be fixed?

Comment: I see next solutions: 1. Don't call method `openPlayStore` in `AppRatingDialog.onClick(View v)` method, but call it after a place has been picked, i.e. in `onActivityResult()` method of your `Activity` or `Fragment`. Or 2. First, open `Play Store` by calling `openPlayStore` method, save some boolean variable to `SharedPreferences` describing that Play Store was open. When user comes back from Play Store to your `Activity/Fragment` check that variable, for example, in `onResume`  method and if it is `true` call `goToPickerActivity()`.

Comment: Okay, that's good enough. Just another small question: how do I make the dialog not disappear when the rest of the screen is tapped?

Comment: You can call method `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` in `AppRatingDialog.onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:
In the library module look for class called `AppRatingDialog.java` add `YOURACTIVITY.goToPickerActivity(**boolean**);` to each view of `onClick` (at line 171) method like this one:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_never_rate) {
        YOURACTIVITY.goToPickerActivity(false); 
        savedNeverShow();
        dismiss();

        if (onRatingDialogListener != null) {
            onRatingDialogListener.onClick();
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate_later) {
        YOURACTIVITY.goToPickerActivity(false);
        dismiss();
        incrementLaunchCount(true);

        if (onRatingDialogListener != null) {
            onRatingDialogListener.onClick();
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate) {
        YOURACTIVITY.goToPickerActivity(true);
        savedNeverShow();
        dismiss();

        if (onRatingDialogListener != null) {
            onRatingDialogListener.onClick();
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity modify your method `goToPickerActivity()` to be something like this:

```
private static void goToPickerActivity(boolean isRate) {
    Intent intent = new com.sucho.placepicker.PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
        .onlyCoordinates(true) //Get only Coordinates from Place Picker
        .showLatLong(true)
        .setLatLong(40.71274, -74.005974)  // Initial Latitude and Longitude the Map will load into (NYC coordinates)
        .setMapZoom(2.5f)  // Map Zoom Level. Default: 14.0
        .build(this);
    if (isRate){
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST_RATE);
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }
```

in method `onActivityResult` check the request code if it's equal to `Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST_RATE` then call method `openStore()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST_RATE) {
        //other code ...
        openStore();
        }
    } 
}

private void openStore() {
    final Uri storeUri = Uri.parse(mStoreLink); // your app store listing link
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, storeUri));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can add handler to `openStore()` if you want to wait for certain time before go to store page:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
    openStore();
}, 1000); // wait for 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to edit the library code, to match up your requirement, first of all, change `appratingdialog` library code. Go to `AppRatingDialog.java` and inside `onClick(View v)` modify the rating button condition like below:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate) {
    savedNeverShow();
    dismiss();

    if (onRatingDialogListener != null) {
        onRatingDialogListener.onClick();
        openPlayStore();    // Just added this extra line here, others are kept in place
    } else {
        openPlayStore();
    }
}
```

Now, inside your app activity, create custom click listener for rating button using `setRateButtonText` like below:

```
AppRatingDialog appRatingDialog = new AppRatingDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTriggerCount(3)
                .setRepeatCount(4)
                .setRateButtonText("Rate Now", clickListener)
                .build();
appRatingDialog.show();
```

Finally, implement the click listener inside your app activity having the `PlacePicker` intent inside `onClick` like below:

```
OnRatingDialogListener clickListener = new OnRatingDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        goToPickerActivity();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a class and extend from `AppRatingDialog`. then by overriding `onClick` method you can do what you want. then by calling `super.onClick` you'll run the library `onClick` method.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.dialog_rating_button_rate) {
            goToPickerActivity();
        }
        super.onClick(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually seem to have this already answered in your original post.

**startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);**

```
public void goToPickerActivity() {
    Intent intent = new com.sucho.placepicker.PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
            .onlyCoordinates(true) //Get only Coordinates from Place Picker
            .showLatLong(true)
            .setLatLong(40.71274, -74.005974)  // Initial Latitude and Longitude the Map will load into (NYC coordinates)
            .setMapZoom(2.5f)  // Map Zoom Level. Default: 14.0
            .build(this);

    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
  }
```

So override `onActivityResult()` from within there you can determine if the activity was successful and then do what you need like below

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (!(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)){
        onBackPressed();
    }else{
        goToPickerActivity()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to update these following dependencies in your build.gradle project level:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:$the_latest_version'
```